# Как передать значения со слайдера на маятник?

Tags: html, css, canvas

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw() {

  var angle = document.getElementById("slider").value;
  var size = Math.min(canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var ox = (canvas.width / 2) >> 0;
  var rPend = size * 0.45;
  var rBall = size * 0.05;
  var x = (ox - rPend * Math.cos(angle)) | 0;
  var y = (rPend * Math.sin(angle) + 2) | 0;



  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBg(context, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBase(context, canvas.width);
  drawLine(context, ox, x, y);
  drawBall(context, x, y, rBall);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

}

function drawBg(context, w, h) {
  context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.51)";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
}

function drawBase(context, w) {
  context.save();
  context.moveTo(0, 2);
  context.lineTo(w, 2);
  context.lineWidth = 3;
  context.stroke();
  context.restore();
}

function drawLine(context, ox, x, y) {
  context.save();
  context.moveTo(ox, 0);
  context.lineTo(x, y);
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.stroke();
  context.restore();
}

function drawBall(context, x, y, rBall) {
  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, rBall, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.fill();
  context.restore();
}
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
#canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

mark.red {
  background-color: #8A02BB;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="center">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="350" height="350"></canvas>
</div>

<h2 style='text-align: center'>
  <mark>
      <mark class = "red">  Изменение угла маятника (в градусах)
      </mark>
</h2>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: допишите пример нормально, чтобы выполнялось тут без ошибок хотя бы

Comment: Так проблема в том, что я не знаю, как исправить ошибку (

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Код перестал функционироавать, помогите разобраться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1114931/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f)